# "With more than..."

Tags: грамматика

How can I say "A book with more than 1000 pages"?

As far as I know, "с более" or "с больше" does not make sense. Someone told me that there's not such a straightforward way to use "более/больше" preceded by a preposition requiring a case other than the accusative.

Comment: It's better to say книга, в которой более/больше тысячи страниц.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) книга с более чем тысячью страницами

2) книга, имеющая более тысячи страниц

Comment: "Тысячей" or "тасячею" are also possible in 1).

Comment: @Yellow Sky In case _тысячей_ the word _страни**цами**_ should be replaced with _стран**иц**_. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28475/%D0%A2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: if anyone wishes to get a sense of how tediously difficult Russian can be, i suggest to review the discussion referenced by @Alex_ander

Answer (score 8):

Whilst @Dmitry's answer is technically 100% correct, I am yet to hear someone use such a construct in a conversation. Admittedly, this particular message is quite cumbersome to communicate across in Russian without sounding as an academic textbook...

So - bearing in mind what you literally asked ("How can I SAY") - a couple of more colloquial options:

- Я тут за ночь прочёл книгу больше чем на триста страниц.
- Представляешь, Сергей Петрович издал книгу - больше тысячи страниц!

Comment: Сергей Пе **тр** ович... Unless `Пертович` is meant to be his last name.

Comment: Indeed. Thnx.  :)

Answer (score 6):

- **Книга объёмом более 1000 страниц.**

You can use this pattern to describe other dimensions as well:

- Гора высотой более 1000 метров.
- Река длиной более 1000 километров.

The dimension (объём, длина, высота) is in the instrumental case.

The word **тысяча** is in the genitive case: **более тысячи.**

Answer (score 5):

If you must use `более`: **Книга более чем с тысячей страниц.**

Anti-prescriptivist as I like to think of myself as, I'm still a little peeved by `с более чем тысячей` and dismayed to see it here twice, but perhaps it's time for me to move on.

Anyway, **книга [длиной] в тысячу с лишним страниц** is what sounds good to me overall.

Answer (score 3):

You could just say:

> Книга с более чем 1000 страницами

This is a literal translation and it makes a perfect sense.

Comment: Btw, how would you spell out "1000" here? :)

Comment: "Тысячей", or "тасячею", or "тысячью": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/тысяча#Declension_2

Comment: With everything else in place, only **тысячью** (or тысяч**ей** стран**иц**).

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Why? This sounds perfectly good to me. Other examples: `журнал с более чем десятью картинками`, `куртка с более чем пятью карманами`. Common pattern: `[Object] с более чем [n] [sub-objects]`. Что не так?

Comment: nouns with such numerals as **сто/сотня**, **тысяча**, **миллион** is a different case than the rest, because with these numerals (which are grammatically nouns) nouns primarily inflect in Genitive case, please have a look at the article on Gramota.ru [**«Тысяче работникам» или «тысяче работников»?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92). According to the explanation your example could work with тысячЬЮ, but not with тысячЕЙ... so i retract my initial comment, but with тысячей it would indeed sound awful